# How to roll up a plane diagonally?

Tags: animation, modifiers, objects

I'm trying to fold a paper from the corner. But when I add the curve modifier the plane gets stretched and deformed.I have tried changing the deform axis and applying the scale and rotation. Didn't work. How to fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here's the blend file

https://pasteall.org/blend/7441067c85854ef386f9ecb58a7bc66e

Comment: hello could you please share your file? copy paste the URL it will create once uploaded: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots Updated the post. Could you please check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have scaled and applied the scale of your curve, it changes the vertices radius, go in *Edit* mode, select all, open the *N* panel and check. Just bring back the *Mean Radius* to 1:

[image]

Comment: +1 green color :D

Comment: Yes, big change today, you made me realize my mistake, thanks Chris